# Magento PHP SQL Query to pull out products from a specific catergory(including children)

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am currently in a pinch and need a tweak to some existing code on my site. There is a PHP SQL query that needs to be modified to pull products from  a specific category. This list then fed into an HTML product carousel. Anyway, currently it's pulling in all products with an image.

```
<?php
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` WHERE `small_image` != 'no_selection'");
 //$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` WHERE `category_ID` = 16");
 while($fins = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                ?>
```

The commented line of code is what I was trying to do, but had no luck. I'm shooting in the dark here. I'm no Magento or PHP expert by any standards. FYI, The front end shows the category ID being 16 for the category that I want. It would be nice to pull it by name, but I'm ok with using ID for simplicity/speed sake.

Thanks for any assistance.

(UPDATE 8-27) 
Entire HTML Code Block:

```
<div class="whiteGradientLarge span-10">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Latest Products</h2>
        <div class="span-10">
            <a href="#" class="prev left"><img src="assets/arrowPrev.png" /></a>
            <ul class="productSlider push-1">

                <?php
                //$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` WHERE `small_image` != 'no_selection'");
                //while($products = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
                $category->load('16'); //your category id here, 16 $catid
                $prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
                foreach ($prodCollection as $product) {
                //get all the product information here... //}
                    ?>
                    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item">
                    <h3><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/store/products/<?php echo $product['url_path']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h3> 
                    <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/store/media/catalog/product<?php echo $product['small_image']; ?>" />
                    <span class="productTitle span-3"><?php  ?></span>
                    </li>
                <?php 
                } ?>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="next right"><img src="assets/arrowNext.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Product will be an object not an array when looping `$prodCollection`.

Comment: @AlanWhitelaw What's the correct syntax to access the properties of the product object? Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: This is the first Google result for "loop magento product" http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/73153/ which should point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks. I read through that. Seems like this is slightly out of my expertise bounds. using GetAttributeText didn't work. I am using the Magento Database model as a reference but it's not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($catid); //your category id here, 16
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
foreach ($prodCollection as $product) {
    //get all the product information here...

    ?>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item">
         <h3><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/store/products/<?php echo $product->getUrlPath(); ?>"><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></a></h3> 
         <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/store/media/catalog/product<?php echo $product->getSmallImage(); ?>" />
         <span class="productTitle span-3"><?php  ?></span>
    </li>
 <?php 
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggested code and the entire HTML block. It's loading a blank element in HTML.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't work just yet. It must be my DB connection? It loads the page and stops working right at the first PHP line. It doesn't go any further. Any ideas for DB connection?